# How to deal with a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, jupyter-notebook, typeerror

I am using the `numpy.arange` function to count by multiples of 99 starting from the number zero but not including any number past 10000. I am getting the following error:

> TypeError unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

There seems to be a mismatch between a list and an int, but there is only one variable:

```
import numpy as np

multiples_of_99 = np.arange([0,10000,99])
multiples_of_99
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-d47e5e9108c6> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
      2 
----> 3 multiples_of_99 = np.arange([0,10000,99])
      4 multiples_of_99

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the `[]`, [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) takes individual arguments for its start, stop and step parameters:

```
np.arange(0, 10000, 99)
```

You can also omit the `start` argument, and alternatively specify this as:

```
np.arange(10000, step=99)
```

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.arange` takes individual `int` arguments, not a `list` of `int`s. You wanted:

```
multiples_of_99 = np.arange(0, 10000, 99)
```

Admittedly, `numpy` could stand to produce a more useful error message in this case; the error is raised when it performs the basic computations necessary to determine the length of the result. Since you passed a single `list` as an argument, it uses it as the `stop` value, assuming a `start` value of `0`; when it does `stop - start`, that's equivalent to typing `[0, 10000, 99] - 0`, which is clearly wrong when you see it spelled out, but `numpy` being an extension module (implemented in C), the Python level traceback can't show you what it was doing when it performed the invalid subtraction.